# Google CalenderAPI OAuth: Error at insertEvent --> TypeError: authClient.request is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I am using nodejs with javascript. I am trying to insert an event to the primary calender but i am always getting a "Error at insertEvent --> TypeError: authClient.request is not a function". I followed the steps from the google docs to setup the api connection and the listEvents function provided by google works fine. After doing the exact same for the insertEvent function with other parameters , there is an error. I dont know what is different to the listEvents code and why it is working there with oAuth but in my self written function its not.

Imports for connection with API

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');
const process = require('process');
const {authenticate} = require('@google-cloud/local-auth');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const { calendar } = require('googleapis/build/src/apis/calendar');
const { auth } = require('google-auth-library');
const { collection } = require('./endpoints/user/UserModel');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'token.json');
const CREDENTIALS_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'credentials.json');
```

Authorization

```
/**
 * Reads previously authorized credentials from the save file.
 *
 * @return {Promise<OAuth2Client|null>}
 */
async function loadSavedCredentialsIfExist() {
  try {
    const content = await fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH);
    const credentials = JSON.parse(content);
    return google.auth.fromJSON(credentials);
  } catch (err) {
    return null;
  }
}

/**
 * Serializes credentials to a file compatible with GoogleAUth.fromJSON.
 *
 * @param {OAuth2Client} client
 * @return {Promise<void>}
 */
async function saveCredentials(client) {
  const content = await fs.readFile(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
  const keys = JSON.parse(content);
  const key = keys.installed || keys.web;
  const payload = JSON.stringify({
    type: 'authorized_user',
    client_id: key.client_id,
    client_secret: key.client_secret,
    refresh_token: client.credentials.refresh_token,
  });
  await fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, payload);
}

/**
 * Load or request or authorization to call APIs.
 *
 */
async function authorize() {
  let client = await loadSavedCredentialsIfExist();
  if (client) {
    return client;
  }
  client = await authenticate({
    scopes: SCOPES,
    keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
  });
  if (client.credentials) {
    await saveCredentials(client);
  }
  return client;
}
```

listEvents function

```
/**
 * Lists the next 10 events on the user's primary calendar.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */

async function listEvents(auth) {
  const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth});
  const res = await calendar.events.list({
    calendarId: 'primary',
    timeMin: new Date().toISOString(),
    maxResults: 10,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
  });
  const events = res.data.items;
  if (!events || events.length === 0) {
    console.log('No upcoming events found.');
    return;
  }
  console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
  events.map((event, i) => {
    const start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
    console.log(`${start} - ${event.summary}`);
  });
}
```

self written function for insertEvent

```
/**
 * Insert an event on the user's primary calendar.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
async function insertEvent(auth, event) {
  try {
    const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth});
    const response = await calendar.events.insert({
      calendarId: "primary",
      resource: event
    });

    if (response['status'] == 200 && response['statusText'] === 'OK') {
      return "Event Inserted sucessfully";
    } else {
      return "Failed to insert event";
    }
  } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Error at insertEvent --> ${error}`);
      return 0;
  }
};
```

The event i wanted to insert

```
// Event für Google Kalender
let event = {
  'Zusammenfassung': `Das ist die Zusammenfassung.`,
  'Beschreibung': `Das ist die Beschreibung.`,
  'Start': {
    'dateTime': dateTime['start'],
    'timeZone': 'Europe'
  },
  'Ende': {
    'dateTime': dateTime['end'],
    'timeZone': 'Europe'
  }
};
```

I wanted to create a new event on the primary calendar of the logged in user. This ended in an TypeError. Inserting of a event failed.

Error Message: "Error at insertEvent --> TypeError: authClient.request is not a function"